# Images selected with gallery are MUCH bigger then when taken with camera

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, camera

in my app a user either picks an image from their image gallery or captures an image with their camera.

When you capture it is added to the gallery of the user.

I have found that the images, besides being the same image have massive changes in size.

Captured: 33kb

CODE:

```java
    if (requestCode == TAKEIMAGE) {
        System.out.println("TAKE IMAGE");
        int photoLength = 0;
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        photoLength = GetBitmapLength(photo);

        SetSubmissionImage(photo, photoLength);
    }
```

Taken from gallery: 1600kb

CODE:

```java
    else if (requestCode == CHOOSEIMAGE) {
        System.out.println("CHOOSE IMAGE");

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
            byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
            bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);

            int photoLength = 0;
            Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);

            bMapArray = null;
            fileis.close();
            bufferedstream.close();



            //rotate to be portrait properly
            try {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(selectedImagePath);
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
                Log.e("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                if (orientation == 6) {
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                }
                else if (orientation == 3) {
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                }
                else if (orientation == 8) {
                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                }
                photo = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), matrix, true); // rotating bitmap
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }

            //photo = GetCompressedBitmap(photo);
            photoLength = GetBitmapLength(photo);
            SetSubmissionImage(photo, photoLength);

        }
```

Comment: So what is the question for us...???

Comment: You have to scale your image particular size as per your requirement.

Comment: The question is why is the gallery image so large compared to captured image data.

Comment: If the camera image data taken is smaller than whats saved to the library WHY?

Comment: And how can i use this HD image from the gallery instead of the crap image im given from the Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Comment: The intent parcelable data has a limited size, so it is impossible to embed big chunk of data into it. BTW, why u get the image directly from intent? I'm using a different approach: When u define the TAKE IMAGE intent, u'll pass the path of the image, right? Then at your `onActivityResult` just use that path to retrieve the image instead of pulling from intent's parcelable data.

Comment: data intent when taking a picture might only include a thumbnail of the picture. Check after where it's saved if you want the full res.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other said in comments you need to start the camera activity with an intent that contains an uri where image will be saved:

```
// create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then in your onActivityResult() method you can retrive the uri and load the image the from the URI in the intent.